# Intrinsics load matrix

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication, sse, intrinsics

Im learning Intrinsics. I dont know how to load a matrix correctly. I want to do matrix multiplication.

This is my code:

```
int i, j, k;

__m128 mat2values = _mm_setzero_ps();
__m128 mat1values = _mm_setzero_ps();
__m128 r = _mm_setzero_ps();

for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < N - 3; j += 4)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < N - 3; k += 4)
        {
            mat1values = _mm_load_ps(&mat1[i][k]);
            mat2values = _mm_load_ps(&mat2[k][j]);

            r = _mm_add_ps(r, _mm_mul_ps(mat1values, mat2values));
        }
        result[i][j] = r.m128_f32[0] + r.m128_f32[1] + r.m128_f32[2] + r.m128_f32[3];

        for (; k < N; k++)
            result[i][j] += mat1[i][j] * mat2[k][j];
    }

}
```

When debugging result will still hold all 0 values after loop.

Comment: Show the declarations of all variables involved. Make it a [mre]

Comment: IDK why you'd get zeros, but note that `_mm_load_ps(&mat2[k][j])` loads `_mm_load_ps(&mat2[k][j + 0..3])`, so that's probably wrong for a simplistic matmul if one matrix isn't already transposed (i.e. stored with contiguous columns).  Are you sure your inputs are non-zero, and your data is actually float, not small `int` values (whose bit-patterns would be subnormal floats whose products would be zero)? Use a debugger to look at variable values as you single-step, and if your load is truly loading zeros, reduce this to a [mcve] about that.

Comment: `__m128 r = _mm_setzero_ps();` should be re-zeroed before every row x column dot-product though, not just once at the top!  Declaring your `__m128` variables inside the narrowest scopes possible would have avoided that bug in the first place.  But that wouldn't explain getting zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the expression

```
    _mm_load_ps(mat1[i][k])
```

returns the correct memory address in float*?

Comment: I also tried (&mat1[i][k]), still the result hold all four 0